# Where does Rider install .NET

Tags: c#, .net, rider, .net-8.0

I've installed .NET through JetBrains Rider.
It appears as installed:
[image]

And my applications can be built under .NET8.0 and ran under .NET8.0 *within* Rider.

I located the .exe (that was built whilst I was using Rider) in `bin/Debug/net8.0/name_of_my_app.exe` and wanted to run it with the terminal. So I opened a terminal and did `name_of_my_app.exe`; it said "You must install .NET to run this application.".
I therefore looked for any `dotnet.exe` I could find but the only two I could find were not .NET8.0:

```
  7.0.10 at [C:\Program Files\JetBrains\JetBrains Rider 2023.3.3\lib\ReSharperHost\windows-x64\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

So my question is: where the heck is my .NET8.0 `dotnet.exe` so that I can add it to my environment variable PATH and so that I don't have to launch an IDE to run my application.

I'm using `Windows 11` and `JetBrains Rider 2023.3.3`.

Comment: It should be here `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk`

Comment: Nothing was there @SvyatoslavDanyliv

Comment: It's not a secret that JetBrains has its own forks of many .NET open source components, from MSBuild to Xamarin bits, and install them with Rider if you don't have the Microsoft ones installed in advance. That works in many cases but whenever you try to follow the Microsoft guides you see the gaps. Like the other comments indicated, do install Microsoft bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never tried to install Rider before installing .NET, but you can check the Rider settings `File` -> `Settings` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Toolset and Build` ([Rider docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Settings_Toolset_and_Build.html)), it should contain info about toolset used. For example:

[image]

But I would recommend to just install it manually - download an appropriate version from [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/8.0), install and then if needed change Rider settings.

Comment: Exaclty what I was looking for! Indeed, I installed Rider first and then .NET through it.